# Search field using Ultraseek

Tags: javascript, html

So i realized today that using IE to do a search on my site, for instance the term "documents" returns the search results.  if i use FireFox or Chrome the data in the input field is not recognized...

now i looked at the code, and realized that there are no  tags around the input fields... BUT if i put them, then IE does not work...

what the heck do i do?

```
<div class="searchbox" id="searchbox">
        <script type="text/ecmascript">
        function RunSearch() {
            window.location = "http://searcher.example.com:8765/query.html?ql=&amp;col=web1&amp;qt=" + document.getElementById("search").value;
        }    
    </script>
        <div class="formSrchr">
              <input type="text" size="20" name="qt" id="search" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="qlOld" id="qlOld" value="" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="colOld" id="colOld value="web1" />
              <input type="image" name="imageField" src="/_images/search-mag.gif" width="20" height="20" onclick="RunSearch();" />
        </div>
</div> <!-- /searchbox -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  It is in the function.  FF and Chrome do not like "&" code, so i just used a plain text amersand sign "&" instead and it woks fine.

Answer (score 0):

It worked on jsbin.com.

However the `id="colOld` tag is not closed. Also firefox and webkit are less forgiving about duplicated ids -- is there another `search` in the document?

Comment: I closed the tag, still nothing.  I replaced the <font> tags and it actually killed the search in all browsers... not sure what i do here?